# Reading in a text file, and separating the string by bracket in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I have a text file that I am feeding with data as a string, using the following lines of Python:

```
    file = open("C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\data.txt", "a")
    file.writelines(str(mathfunction(readField())))
    file.flush()
    file.close()
```

in the format as follows:

[image]

Every input into the text file consists of an array of three items.

My goal is to extract the third item from each input, convert it to a float, and then store these values in a new array.  So, ideally, in the above case, the array would contain:

`[1.0087890625, 0.4404296875, 0.4404296875]`

I tried the following:

```
data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\data.txt", sep="]", header = None)
data.head()
```

[image]

and it returned the data in what looks like a string format.

What are the next steps that I should take, in order to isolate the third item in each subarray, and store it all in one array?

**EDIT: Here is some data from data.txt**

```
[0.0263671875, 0.03515625, 1.0087890625][0.01171875, 0.0146484375, 0.4404296875][0.01171875, 0.0146484375, 0.4404296875]
```

Comment: What if you use `sep = "]|["`? or maybe `sep = "(]|[)|(]&[)"`?

Comment: Can you please post a text copy of `df.head()` please?

Comment: Maybe the next step would be to watch this [2015 Pycon USA talk](http://pandas.pydata.org/talks.html#pycon-us-2015).

Comment: Can you open ```data.txt``` in a text editor, copy a few lines and paste them here?  Do you have to have a pandas solution.

Comment: @wwii I have added the first three lines.  It doesn't need to be a pandas solution.  But it is preferred, because I'll be processing the data using a pandas function.

Comment: On the off chance you want to use regex separators, I messed around with it and was able to get it working with `data=pd.read_csv('test.txt', sep="\[|\]\[|\]", header=None)`, but the data in the first row is wrong `data[0]` outputs `0   NaN`, but everything else is right. So you could just slice off the first row and then apply the lambda function from nanojohn's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can then split by `','` commas after reading in the data:

```
data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\data.txt", sep="]", header = None)
data = data.iloc[0]
data = data.apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[2]).astype(float).tolist()
```

If you want to keep the data in a Pandas Series, just remove the `tolist()` portion above. Here is an example:

```
data = pd.DataFrame([['[1,2,3','[3,4,5','[4,5,6']])
print(data)
        0       1       2
0  [1,2,3  [3,4,5  [4,5,6

data = data.iloc[0]
data = data.apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[2]).astype(float).tolist()
print(data)
[3.0, 5.0, 6.0]
```

Comment: Can you not use regex separators when reading the data? Also, this doesn't get rid of the bracket at the beginning

Comment: It should get rid of the beginning bracket, since OP is only interested in the 3rd item in the list

Comment: Oh, good point. I was focusing on the wrong issue. Nice answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I recognize that it may be the way my dataset is being stored, but I am receiving the error: `AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: try forcing the data to be recognized as a string: `data = data.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[2]).astype(float)`

Answer (score 0):

I would back up a bit...
If `mathfunction(readField())` produces a list of lists, write the lines to the csv file like this:

```
for line in mathfunction(readField()):
   line = ','.join(line) + '\n'
   file.write(line)
```

Then `pd.read_csv()` will produce a more manageable dataframe and you can use the `dtype` parameter to convert the data to floats when it is read.
.